# kube-proxy: Another app is currently holding the xtables lock

Tags: kubernetes, kube-proxy

We've been getting intermittent connectivity/dns issues in our Kubernetes cluster running 1.10 on Ubuntu.

We've been all over the bug reports/etc., and nearest we can figure a process is holding onto `/run/xtables.lock` and it's causing issues in a kube-proxy pod.

One of the kube-proxy pods bound to a worker has this error repeating in the logs:

```
E0920 13:39:42.758280       1 proxier.go:647] Failed to ensure that filter chain KUBE-SERVICES exists: error creating chain "KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES": exit status 4: Another app is currently holding the xtables lock. Stopped waiting after 5s.
E0920 13:46:46.193919       1 proxier.go:647] Failed to ensure that filter chain KUBE-SERVICES exists: error creating chain "KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES": exit status 4: Another app is currently holding the xtables lock. Stopped waiting after 5s.
E0920 14:05:45.185720       1 proxier.go:647] Failed to ensure that filter chain KUBE-SERVICES exists: error creating chain "KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES": exit status 4: Another app is currently holding the xtables lock. Stopped waiting after 5s.
E0920 14:11:52.455183       1 proxier.go:647] Failed to ensure that filter chain KUBE-SERVICES exists: error creating chain "KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES": exit status 4: Another app is currently holding the xtables lock. Stopped waiting after 5s.
E0920 14:38:36.213967       1 proxier.go:647] Failed to ensure that filter chain KUBE-SERVICES exists: error creating chain "KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES": exit status 4: Another app is currently holding the xtables lock. Stopped waiting after 5s.
E0920 14:44:43.442933       1 proxier.go:647] Failed to ensure that filter chain KUBE-SERVICES exists: error creating chain "KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES": exit status 4: Another app is currently holding the xtables lock. Stopped waiting after 5s.
```

These errors started happening about 3 weeks ago and we've been unable thus far to remedy it. Because the problems were intermittent we didn't track it down to this until now.

We think this is causing one of the kube-flannel-ds pods to be in a perpetual `CrashLoopBackOff` state as well:

```
NAME                                 READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-78fcdf6894-6z6rs             1/1       Running            0          40d
coredns-78fcdf6894-dddqd             1/1       Running            0          40d
etcd-k8smaster1                      1/1       Running            0          40d
kube-apiserver-k8smaster1            1/1       Running            0          40d
kube-controller-manager-k8smaster1   1/1       Running            0          40d
kube-flannel-ds-amd64-sh5gc          1/1       Running            0          40d
kube-flannel-ds-amd64-szkxt          0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   7077       40d
kube-proxy-6pmhs                     1/1       Running            0          40d
kube-proxy-d7d8g                     1/1       Running            0          40d
kube-scheduler-k8smaster1            1/1       Running            0          40d
```

Most bug reports around `/run/xtables.lock` seem to show it was resolved July 2017, but we're seeing this on a new setup. We seem to have appropriate chain configurating in iptables.

running `fuser /run/xtables.lock` returns nothing.

Does anybody have insight on this? it's causing a lot of pain

Comment: Where is iptables lock happening? on the nodes?

Comment: It appears to be on a worker node.

The only symptom of this is that about twice a day during work hours - around 10-10:40am, and around 5:30pm - our nodes experience issues with DNS lookups for about 2 minutes. This is what started us investigating what the cluster was doing.

We may try to just bring the cluster down and restart it, see if it helps. We'd need to plan for that off-hours, but it's doable. But I'd like to know why it's happening.

Comment: Have you seen any suspicious events for failed `kube-flannel-ds-amd64-szkxt` Pod?

Answer (score 3):

So after a bit more digging we were able to find a reason code with this command:

`kubectl -n kube-system describe pods kube-flannel-ds-amd64-szkxt`

The name of the pod is going to change in a different installation of course, but the reason code for a termination was outputted as:

```
   Last State:     Terminated
     Reason:       OOMKilled
     Exit Code:    137
```

We had missed this Reason code earlier (we were mostly focused on the exit code of 137), and it means out of memory; killed.

By default, kube-flannel-ds gets a max memory allocation of `100Mi` - this is too low apparently. There are other issues logged around changing this default in the reference config, but our fix was to adjust the max limit to `256Mi`

Changing the configuration is one step, just issue:

`kubectl -n kube-system edit ds kube-flannel-ds-amd64`

and change the value from `100Mi` under the limits -> memory to something higher; we did `256Mi`.

By default these pods will only update `OnDelete`, so you then need to delete the pod that's in a `CrashLoopBackOff`, after which it will be re-created with the updated values.

You can roll through and delete any on other nodes as well I suppose, but we only deleted the one that kept failing.

Here's references to some issues that helped us track this down:

https://github.com/coreos/flannel/issues/963
https://github.com/coreos/flannel/issues/1012